# awk to print a previous line based on a pattern only if it precedes a pattern

Tags: awk

I have an application log which has request and response and in between some sql queries. I would like to find the request request line followed by a sql that take a more than a specific time , for example i have the following log snippet,  and I would like an awk oneliner that spits the following line- which finds a request causing a sql that runs more than 1 second.

11:01:19:518         FfsFrm_Test_Buffer     20

log snippet-

11:01:19:518         FfsFrm_View_Buffer     20
INPUT buffer follows

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 0.004383 seconds

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '24'

11:01:19:549         ODA               20
Calculated OCI buffer size of 3516

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '25' previously used by statement '24'

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
SELECT field, field2 from table  WHERE STGS_ID=:bvC2W   Bound Values: AMS52|

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 0.00125 seconds
OUTPUT buffer follows

11:01:19:518         FfsFrm_View_Buffer     20
INPUT buffer follows

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 0.004383 seconds

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '24'

11:01:19:549         ODA               20
Calculated OCI buffer size of 3516

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '25' previously used by statement '24'

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
SELECT field, field2 from table  WHERE STGS_ID=:bvC2W   Bound Values: AMS52|

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 0.00125 seconds
OUTPUT buffer follows

11:01:19:518         FfsFrm_Correct_Buffer     20
INPUT buffer follows

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 0.004383 seconds

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '24'

11:01:19:549         ODA               20
Calculated OCI buffer size of 3516

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '25' previously used by statement '24'

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
SELECT field, field2 from table  WHERE STGS_ID=:bvC2W   Bound Values: AMS52|

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 0.00125 seconds
OUTPUT buffer follows

11:01:19:518         FfsFrm_Test_Buffer     20
INPUT buffer follows

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 1.004383 seconds

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '24'

11:01:19:549         ODA               20
Calculated OCI buffer size of 3516

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
Acquiring CursorPoolItem for statement '25' previously used by statement '24'

11:01:19:549         DBA               20
SELECT field, field2 from table  WHERE STGS_ID=:bvC2W   Bound Values: AMS52|

11:01:19:549         DBA               10
SQL executed in: 0.00125 seconds
OUTPUT buffer follows

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that this site doesn't have a code writing service included. You'll probably get helpful answers if you describe the patterns exactly (for example in some form of regex) and add desired input and output to your question. You mention `XML`, but there is no `XML` in your question. Furthermore, please update your question and format the input / output, so that other readers can understand your problems. Currently, it looks all mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

I think I got it like this

awk '/_Buffer/{req = $0}/SQL executed in:/ && $4 > 1 {print req}' test.log

look for pattern1 and pattern2, save the line to req when first pattern is found, print at the end.

Comment: This should be part of your orignial Q. Note that a good question will have a small set of sample data, expected output from that input, current code/output/error msgs and your thoughts about why things aren't working. Please read , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and maybe the http://stackoverflow.com/tour before posting more questions here. (I didn't downvote, but I would be entitled to :-/) Good luck.